# ASP.net mvc5 upgrade from mvc3 loses HTTPContext.User

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of upgrading a legacy app that I inherited from MVC3 to MVC5 and somehow I broke the HTTPContext.User object.

The app has a custom authentication mechanism that seems to be working correctly as it returns a proper User object to the rest of the pipeline.  Specifically, in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.GetType().FullName.Equals("Citation.AMS.Users.UserContext", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IAuditor auditor = CoreFactory.AuditorCreate())
                    {
                        auditor.WriteAudit(HttpContext.Current, "Compliance");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    using (ILogger log = CoreFactory.LoggerCreate())
                    {
                        log.WriteFatalError("Exception in Application_BeginRequest::Audit.", ex);
                    }
                }
```

The check for HTTPContext.Current.User returns the correct object above.  But by the very next method call:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = null;
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[CookieHelper.CookieName];
        if (cookie != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie.Values[CookieHelper.CultureName]))
        {
            ci = new CultureInfo(cookie.Values[CookieHelper.CultureName]);
        }
        else
        {
```

The object is converted then to an RolePrincipal instead of the correct User type.

There must be some processing done between those two method calls in the pipeline but I can't figure out what's happening between them that would change the user object.

In the original code base, this doesn't happen.  I've also created a new branch based on the MVC3 branch and upgraded all the nuget packages and updated the web.config files as I found issues and that seems to work better (don't want to go that route because my other branch has a lot of other changes that would be challenging to replicate.)

Can someone tell me what I'm missing or how to find out why the object is changing between these method calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it was custom javascript that was redirecting my controllers.